# Train CNN model with images in sub-folders (Train, Val, Test)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am developing a convolution neural network (CNN) model to predict whether a patient is in categories 1, 2, or 3. I use Keras on top of TensorFlow.

I have a 145 neuropsychological subjects dataset, classified into three categories (1=normal, 2= …., 3= cognitive impaired). In each patient's dataset, I have 90 sets of MRI scan images taken at the same time and inside each MRI folder, the summary the total dataset is 145 and inside the total dataset are subfolders for each patient having 90 MRI images.

I learned how to deal with the basic “Cat-Dog-CNN-Classifier”, it was easy as I put all the cat & dog images into a single folder to train the network which is not my case. But how do I tackle the problem in my neuropsychological subjects dataset and do a prediction using all the images per subject at once after training?

I checked similar question was asked but the answers weren't clear and did not work after applying.
[Train CNN model with multiple folders and sub-folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664485/train-cnn-model-with-multiple-folders-and-sub-folders)

Thank You, please suggest some algorithms I can use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you want to learn from all the images for a subject at once your input shape needs to include the number of images as a dimension like this:

(num_of_images, x_pix, y_pix, channels)

for example if you downscale your scans to be 256*256 RGB images then your shape would be:
(90,256,256,3)

That is quite a large input to process, I would split these into much smaller groups using just a sub set of the scans like (10,256,256,3)

It is very likely that you will not be able to pre-process all of the images into memory, to resolve this you should use a generator as your input, try this template:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
import numpy as np
class Custom_Generator(Sequence):

    #initialise generator
    def __init__(self, file_sets, label, batch_size) :
        self.file_sets = file_sets
        self.label = label
        self.batch_size = batch_size
    
    #returns number of data batches this generator will return
    def __len__(self) :
        return (np.ceil(len(self.file_sets) / float(self.batch_size))).astype(np.int)
  
    #returns a single batch 
    def __getitem__(self, idx) :

        #do all the operations you need to load and pre-process your data here

        return x, y
```

make a generator for your training and validation set and use that when you call model.fit()

Alternatively check out
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

as used here
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation

For the model it's self start with a simple CNN like you've seen in the tutorials get your pre-processing pipeline sorted, and you can see what your model scores. If you still need to improve you could try one of these:
https://keras.io/api/applications/